# InvalidTextRepresentation: Invalid input syntax for type bigint:"All Forms"

Tags: django, database, postgresql, psycopg2, dbmigrate

I had a field in my model with

```
book_classes = (("","Select Form"),("1",'F1'),("2",'F2'),("3",'F3'),("4",'F4'),("All Forms","All Forms"))
b_classes = models.CharField('Form',max_length=9,choices=book_classes,default="n/a")
```

And then changed it to

```
b_class =models.ForeignKey(ClassBooks,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Where

```
class ClassBooks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I'm now stuck because when I try to migrate I get an error.

```
Invalid input syntax for type bigint:"All Forms"
```

Makemigrations and migrate worked well in development. When I pushed to digital ocean, the migrate returned the error stated.
What do I need to do, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Foreign Key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). By default a FK field is going to use the Primary Key of the referenced table(model), in this case the `id` field of `ClassBooks`. The `id` field is an integer so you get the error when trying to use a string field. To make this work, from the documentation link :

> ForeignKey.to_field

> The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object. If you reference a different field, that field must have unique=True.

Which in your case becomes:

```
b_class =models.ForeignKey(ClassBooks,to_field='name',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This assumes that the `name` field has a `Unique` constraint on it.

Though I am not sure how `"", "1", "2" ...` map to `ClassBooks.name`.

Comment: I had b_classes = models.CharField('Form',max_length=9,choices=book_classes,default="n/a"). The default="n/a". It's also haunting me. After I implemented your suggestion, I got this error in migrate,. Key(b_class_id)=("n/a") is not present in table  books_app_classbooks

Comment: That is the point of a FK the values is the child(referencing) table have to be in the parent(referenced) table. I am still not sure how `b_class` relates to `name` in any case. Assuming `"", "1", "2" ` are actually values in `name` then you need to add `"n/a"` to `name`.

Comment: Very true, I have to add "n/a" as one of the 'name's. It has finally been solved. Thank you very much.....

Comment: Why is this the case? Why is it trying to relate to the string field on `ClassBooks` instead of its PK? We're running into an identical case, but there is no reason our name field should be unique and the key to the model.

Comment: Because @fakeMake changed the `ForeignKey()` to be as I show in my answer:`b_class =models.ForeignKey(ClassBooks,to_field='name',on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. This explicitly points at the `name` field.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, forgot to tag you in my previous comment. Look at it for answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to lose db.sqlite3 try to delete migrations first

Step 1: Delete the db.sqlite3 file.

Step 2 : $ python manage.py migrate

Step 3 : $ python manage.py makemigrations

Step 4: Create the super user using $ python manage.py createsuperuser

new db.sqlite3 will generates automatically

Comment: I'm using posgress in both development and production.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576004/simple-way-to-reset-django-postgresql-database